# all the possible combinations to create triangles in a determined graph.

Tags: combinatorics, python, sagemath

Im studying about graphs.

I'm trying to get all the possible combinations to create triangles in a determined graph

[image: figure 1]

For example for the complete graph $K_5$, I want to get in **sage** or **python** the $10$ triangles that I can form with adjacent matrices, where $1$ is the red edge and $0$ the main diagonal and where there is no edge.

I have tried with combinations but I only get the $120$ possible combinations where in most cases they are not triangles. example:

[image]

Code: thanks to saulspatz:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

triangle = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range (i+1,5)]

def matrices():
    for t in combinations(triangle,3):
        m = np.zeros((5,5))
        for c in t:
            m[c]=1
        yield m+m.transpose()

M = [m for m in matrices()]
```

My algorithm using **matrices()** is very inefficient, since it takes a lot of time for larger graphs

Comment: You have **5** available vertices and you want to **choose 3** of them and those will act as the vertices of the triangle.  Does the phrase "*5 choose 3*" ring a bell to you?  What do you know about binomial coefficients?

Comment: Well it does take $O(n^3)$ time, but there are $O(n^3)$ triangles, so you can't do any better asymptotically.  I really don't think you can do much better in python. `combinations` is supposed to be highly efficient compiled C code.  If the matrices are very large, it would be better to use a sparse format.  That would certainly save some time.

Comment: Starting from a description of the graph, with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, one can do $O(mn)$. The key is to start from the edges, rather than from arbitrary triples of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

## Enumerate triangles in a graph using SageMath

Let us work on the example in the question, the complete graph
on five vertices.

```
sage: G = graphs.CompleteGraph(5)
```

### Using `subgraph_search_iterator`

One way that works not only for triangles, but for any subgraph,
is to use the built-in method `subgraph_search_iterator`.

```
sage: T = graphs.CycleGraph(3)
sage: triangles_a = G.subgraph_search_iterator(T)
sage: len(list(triangles_a))
60
```

Note that this list contains all the labeled triangles in G;
so each triangle is there 6 times, for each starting vertex
and each orientation.

### Using `edges`

For the special case of triangles, one may instead iterate
through edges of `G`, and look for common neighbours of the
endpoints of edges.

```
sage: triangles_b = []
sage: for (i, j) in G.edges(labels=False):
....:     for k in G.neighbors(i):
....:         if k in G.neighbors(j):
....:             triangles_b.append((i, j, k))
....:
sage: len(triangles_b)
30
```

Here, each triangle is there three times, once for each choice
of an edge of this triangle.

### Using `edges` and comparisons

Getting each triangle only once is easy if there is a total order
on vertices of `G` (e.g. in our example, they are integers), one
can limit the enumeration above to get each triangle only once.

```
sage: triangles_c = []
sage: for (i, j) in G.edges(labels=False):
....:     for k in G.neighbors(i):
....:         if k > i and k > j and k in G.neighbors(j):
....:             triangles_c.append((i, j, k))
....:
sage: len(triangles_c)
10
```

Finally, here is the list for the example in the question:

```
sage: triangles_c
[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: thanks Samuel Lelièvre, Using edges and comparisons is interesting,                                I also try to do this..        mm I can not put my algorithm in this comment,